# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS while using ServerName as www.example.com in httpd

Tags: apache, redirect, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, http-redirect

So Basically I wrote a code to redirect all my http(:80) request to https(:443),
https-redirect.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
#ServerAlias *example.com
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
# LogLevel debug
# ErrorLog /etc/httpd/logs/error_http.log
# CustomLog /etc/httpd/logs/error_http.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

at first it did work i.e. when someone types example.com it redirected to https://www.example.com However when someone types [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) it redirects to http://www.example.com instead of https

So **to overcome this i used `ServerAlias *example.com` (and even `ServerName www.example.com`) here it did work but I ended up getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS** can anyone please help I can't even find a proper explaination anywhere. I even tried finding for potential loop but couldn't.
reverse-proxy.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName example.com
 ServerAlias *example.com

 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyRequests Off
 AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

 <Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
 </Proxy>

 RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto http
 RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 80

 ProxyPass "/" "http://example_ip:8080/"
 ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://example_ip:8080/"

 LogLevel debug
 ErrorLog /etc/httpd/logs/error.log
 CustomLog /etc/httpd/logs/error.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The above code is the one to redirect :8080 request to :80

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use

```
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

instead of

```
ServerAlias *example.com
```

because you want to redirect your 3rd level domains and not everything hitting your web server endgin with 'example.com'.

When you create redirect you need to make sure to have an "exclusion" condition to avoid any loop: the url your redirect to, shouldn't trigger the redirect itself or it will create a loop which leads to the same error you're facing now (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS). This error happens after 20 redirects.

Did you check if the application running on port 443 doesn't redirect back to http?
You should use curl with '-v' option to make sure this doesn't happen.

In the end, "proxyPass" and "proxyPassRevers" are used when you want your server to act as a proxy to let client connect to resources hosted on a server not publicly accessible or on a port that might be firewalled.

Your configuration says "when someone asks for / on example.com, show him the content of the application running on port 8080 of the server behind the ip of example.com'. If apache resolve 'example.com' with a public ip, your apache will try to contact that ip (which might not be his own private ip) on port 8080. Depending on how your network is configured, this might now work or require some firewall policies.
To avoid this, you can use the private ip running the application on port 8080 OR an internal domain name apache can resolve to the correct ip address AND if you need the endpoint to be contacted preserving the original hostname (i.e. [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) you should enable 'ProxyPreserveHost'.

Comment: At first it was `ServerAlias *.example.com` when it didn't work I changed it. I just checked with curl -v its not redirecting back to port 80. If you check the code ProxyPreserveHost is already enabled should I enable it in https-redirect.conf too.

Comment: If 'ServerAlias *.example.com' isn't working, you have something in your configuration/environment interfering (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html). You should place ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse in the vitualhost actually handling the requests, not in the one doind the redirection from http to https. As you wrote, since the app is not redirecting back to 80/443, you should definitly check why it's not and implement the proper configurations/modifications.

Comment: When I said `ServerAlias *.example.com` didn't work I meant its giving me ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS, ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse is in a different .conf file and redirection is done in different .conf file.

Comment: Checking the link i posted in my previous comment, shows ServerAlias *.example.com is valid: if the problem occurs when you use it, it means a condition is matched and a redirect loop is started. You can increased rewriterule log level to find ouot what's happening: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging